# How do I connect to SQLite with Simple.Data.SQLite

Tags: sqlite, ado.net, simple.data

I wrote this code in Webmatrix 2.0 beta:

```
string Dbfile=HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("data/db.db3");
var Db = Simple.Data.Database.OpenFile(Dbfile);
```

Simple.Data.SimpleDataException: No ADO Provider found.

why??

I'm sure that I have included the reference:

packages.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Simple.Data.Ado" version="0.16.1.0" />
  <package id="Simple.Data.Core" version="0.16.1.0" />
  <package id="Simple.Data.Sqlite" version="0.16.0.0" />
  <package id="System.Data.SQLite" version="1.0.80.0" />
</packages>
```

Comment: Note that Mark cleaned up a lot of "No ADO Provider found" errors in v0.17 and higher. If you haven't already tried this, update your Simple.Data and Simple.Data.Ado packages to 0.18.2.1.

Answer (score 1):

In my test application conn is the physical path including the the db filename and calling

```
cn = Database.OpenConnection(conn);
```

works for me.  When I used OpenFile I also received the No ADO Provider error.

I am using (from NuGet):

- Simple.Data.Core 0.16.1.0
- Simple.Data.Ado 0.16.1.0
- System.Data.SQLite 1.0.80.0
- Simple.Data.Sqlite 0.16.0.0
- System.Data.SQLite 1.0.80.0

Answer (score 0):

Getting the dlls required for the System.Data.SQlite can be hassle. If you want to do it quickly then download the [Nuget extension for VS 2010](http://nuget.org/packages/Simple.Data.Sqlite/Download). Then you can get the dlls from the extensions console.

Make sure you read the [extension installations instructions](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/installing-nuget).